# Undo “unfollow post” action on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I accidentally clicked “unfollow post” on Facebook. Is there a way to reverse or undo this action?

Answer (score 1):

[In this post](http://blog.jxt.com.au/2012/05/221/) you can see the way in this image, if you unfollowed in notfications:

[image]

If you unfolowed a post from the wall there will be a similar placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

There's a follow post option, which allows you to subscribe to the post again

[image]